# My Simple JavaScript code using isNaN is not working

Tags: javascript, html, isnan

I am taking introductory JavaScript course, and I learned about `isNaN` function.
I wrote a simple program where JS repeat `prompt` method unless user type number in the prompt.
I don't know why my code doesn't work as I expected. If you input on the prompt twice, the program automatically escapes while loop.

```
<script>
    
     var userSalary = prompt("Hi, type a number!");

    
    while(isNaN(userSalary)){
        parseFloat(prompt(userSalary+ " is not number..."));
        userSalary.reset()
    }
    
    alert("Thank you!");
    
        
</script>
```

Comment: What is `userSalary.reset()` supposed to do? `prompt()` returns a string. A string doens't have a `reset()` function.

Comment: did you mean `alert` instead of `alart` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't setting the value of `userSalary` in the loop:

```
var userSalary = prompt("Hi, type a number!");

while(isNaN(userSalary)){
    userSalary = parseFloat(prompt(userSalary + " is not number..."));
}
alert("Thank you!");
```